# Запятая перед союзом КАК (два предложения)

Tags: обороты-с-как

1. *Она стала относиться к нему **как к своему ребенку**.*

Ответ Грамоты: Запятая перед КАК не требуется, так как сравнительный оборот **тесно связан со сказуемым.**

2. *Мы относились к Ване(,) **как к своему человеку.***

Вопрос с другого форума.
Следует  ли считать, что оборот не обособляется по той же причине? Или обособление все-таки возможно (например, выбор решения по контексту)?

Comment: Спасибо участнику @shampar за помощь при решении задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без предлога *к* и/или без определения связь оборота со сказуемым могла бы быть действительно тесной (*Она стала относиться к нему как своему ребенку*; *Она стала относиться к нему как  ребенку*; *Мы относились к Ване как своему*). В обоих же примерах из вопроса должно применяться правило обособления сравнительного оборота.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня. Я тоже обратил внимание на союз К и думаю, что обособление здесь обязательным не является. Но может, это зависит от контекста, ведь по теории сравнительный оборот может обособляться или не обособляться в конкретной ситуации.  Можно ли подобрать ситуацию для предложения (2) без обособления?

Comment: Опять же без предлога: *Мы относились к Ване как своему человеку — всегдашнему генератору идей*.

Comment: В вашем примере все-таки меняется смысл, но идея верная: ударение должно перейти на оборот при безударном сказуемом, тогда не будет обособления. Кстати, союз К обязателен по словарю: относится к кому-чему.

Comment: Я уверен был, что понятно... О втором К разговор. Разве **относиться к Ване как своему** (здесь без К) недопустимая форма?

Comment: @Sharon: _«Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня. Я тоже обратил внимание на **союз К** и думаю, что обособление здесь обязательным не является…»; «Кстати, **союз К** обязателен по словарю: относится к кому-чему.»_  === **К — не союз!** ПРЕДЛОГ.

Comment: Я думала, что будет понятно...  Здесь К обозначает союзно-предложное сочетание союз + предлог.

Answer (score 1):

1. **О тесной связи оборота со сказуемым**

У глагола "отнестись" **сильное управление,** поэтому дополнение ***к кому-чему*** требуется обязательно. Отсюда следует представление **о тесной связи** сказуемого с оборотом. Но эта вакансия заполнена местоимением ***к нему.*** Так что необходимости в обособлении тоже нет, оборот рассматривается на общих основаниях, а это **факультативное обособление.**

**ОТНЕСТИСЬ**, -несусь, -несёшься; отнёсся, -неслась, -лось; отнёсшийся; отнесясь; св. 1. **к кому-чему.** Составить своё представление о ком-, чём-л.; повести себя, встретить, принять что-л. каким-л. образом. О. к подросткам с пониманием. **О. к кому-л. как к своему недругу.**

2. В примерах **из Нацкорпуса** оборот обособлен, поэтому в предложении (2) его следует обособить тоже:

*Мы относИлись к Ване, **как к своемУ человеку.** Два ударения: на сказуемом, и на обороте.*

3. Могу предположить, что нет обособления при таком контексте:

*Мы относились к Ване **как к своемУ человеку**, чужим для нас он никогда нЕ был.* Ударение переходит **на оборот**, сказуемое в безударной позиции.

4. Почему в ответе Грамоты **нет обособления**, трудно сказать. Ситуация там такая же.

**Из Нацкорпуса:**

**Г. Ермолаев. Несвоевременные мысли** // Мосты. Сб. статей к 50-летию русской революции, 1967
В одной статье-воспоминании говорится, что Ленин даже в 1918 году относился **к Горькому, как к своему человеку**, который обязательно вернется к большевикам.

**В. П. Катаев. Трава забвенья (1964-1967)**
Вы знаете эту единственную болезнь Бунина, — сказала Вера Николаевна с полуулыбкой обратившись **ко мне, как к «своему человеку»,** перед которым нечего стесняться.

**А. А. Фадеев. Молодая гвардия (1943-1951)**
— Что у вас за секреты? — ревниво спрашивала Клава у Вани, когда уже в полной темноте они сидели в горнице в доме Ивана Никаноровича и мама Клавы, давно, а особенно после событий на переправе, относившаяся **к Ване, как к своему человеку в доме,** спокойно спала на пышно взбитой, воздушной и жаркой до дурмана казачьей перине.

Мотоциклист даже откозырял Кате, — чувствовалось, что он относится к ней уже **не только как к своему человеку, а и как к человеку важному**.